# Where is Excel's Paste Special Operations in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I want to copy a cell with 100 in it, and paste special - multiply, to multiply a range by that 100

[image]

Comment: Note: the above screen shot is from Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in Google Sheets. All you have in Google Sheets is this:

[image: 0]