# How can I add 1 to numbers in specific cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some cells that just have plain integer values and would like a way to add 1 to them all without having to manually do it in each cell. Sorry if this is really simple; I have little to no experience with spreadsheets.

Answer (score 3):

Excel has a special paste option which lets you add a number, say 1, to all cells in the selected range. Sadly, Google Sheets doesn't have it: [Where is Excel's Paste Special Operations in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129188/136642)

That means you'll have to perform multiple steps, with some temporary cells, to do this:

1. Create a cell with a formula like this one: `=A1+1`

   [image]
2. Use the autofill function, by double clicking the little square in the right corner or by dragging it down. Select all newly created cells:

   [image]
3. Select the original cells, and choose 'Paste **values** only' from the Edit → Paste special menu:

   [image]
4. That increases the values of the cells by one. You can now remove the temporary cells.

   [image]